# I am trying to run this code and it says invalid type, however I have already created a class with the same name. I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: apex, force.com-ide

[image]I am trying to run this code and it says invalid type, however I have already created a class with the same name. I can't figure out what's wrong. 
[image]

Thanks everyone. It was an issue of Eclipse not synchronized with server (my Salesforce account). Thanks @DerekF @JesseMilburn for the help.

Comment: try using the with sharing keyword in the class definition

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't deployed your class to your org. Been forever since I have used Eclipse, and if I remember correctly saving the class doesn't automatically deploy it.

Comment: That little yellow exclamation mark (to the left of the line number 1 at the top of your class) probably means that your `BankAcct` class didn't actually get saved to Salesforce. Try to save that class again, and then [edit your question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/142307/edit) to include the error (or warning) message.

Comment: Thanks so much. I just synchronized it with server and it got complied. @DerekF

Comment: @DerekF I think that's the answer...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `BankAcct` class had only been saved locally, but not to Salesforce. Thus, when you try to instantiate an object of that class in anonymous apex, Salesforce has no idea what a `BankAcct` is.

The indicator here is the yellow exclamation mark immediately to the left of the first line of code in Eclipse. It's small, and easy to miss, but it should also show up in 'problems' tab below the code window.

While I don't currently use Eclipse (I've been using Atom with Mavensmate-app for the better part of a year), I do remember coming across similar issues on occasion.

From what I remember, the two most common issues that result in warnings rather than errors are:

- There was a change made to a file in Salesforce between the time that you last refreshed from Salesforce, and now (when you attempt to save the file)
- Eclipse couldn't connect to Salesforce for one reason or another (like bad credentials in your project config)

Most times, I'd be able to fix this by refreshing from the server.
In Eclipse, you can refresh a single file from server (navigate to the file in the package explorer, right click, Force.com -> refresh from server), which is generally a lot faster than refreshing the entire project.

The only real caution that you need to take is that this can wipe out some (or all) of the work that you've been developing since your last refresh. The simplest way to handle this is to just copy/paste your work into something like notepad.